# Access the contents of a Text box that is part of a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, custom-controls

Ok, so I am new to custom controls, and need be able to get the contents of a text box that is part of a custom user control.

[image: Control]

So say I want to access the text that the user has entered in the Name Textbox, how would I do this? What would I have to add to the code for the control? Or is there a way to just reference it from the form that the control is on?

Here is the code for the control:

```
public partial class CharacterControl : UserControl
{
    public CharacterControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void get_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        starttime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    }

    private void get_end_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        endtime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    }
}
```

Comment: Change the textbox access modifier to public.

Comment: Create a public property, can be read-only if you want only user to be able to modify

Comment: @Leonel That worked thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do is set the access modifier to public.